# using WHERE clause in INSERT trigger SQL

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert, sum, where-clause

I am trying to insert a sum of prices from another table.

```
INSERT INTO Invoice_Of_Supplier (OrderSupplierID, PaymentStatus, Cost)
VALUES (
( SELECT OrderSupplierID FROM inserted),
0,
(SELECT SUM([Price(RUB)]) FROM Car
  JOIN OrderOfSupplier_Car AS osc ON osc.CarID=Car.CarID 
where osc.OrderSupplierID = (select OrderSupplierID from inserted)))
```

I have a `Car` table with fields `price` , `CarID` etc;

`Order_Of_Supplier` table with fields `OrderSupplierID`, `SupplierID`;

And `Order_Of_Supplier_Car` table in which there is a number of cars for each order( fields are `CarID`, `OrderSupplierID`)

**I need to insert a row in table 'InvoiceOfSupplier' with fields 'OrderSupplierID', `PaymentStatus` and `Cost`.**

`OrderSupplierID` and `PaymentStatus` are ok, but `Cost` is `NULL` and I cant understand why. 
When i change on `osc.OrderSupplierID = 2`(getting `OrderSupplierID` directly) it doesn't work niether.
it Only works, when i remove all conditions like 'WHERE', but in this case it gets the 'Price(RUB)' of all orders, not the one I need.

*EDIT:*
The problem is that at the moment data was inserted in `Order_Of_Supplier` there was no data in `Order_Of_Supplier_Car`.

Comment: `SUM([Price(RUB)])` .. price is a function?

Comment: Impossible to help without knowing more about your data.   How do we know that you aren't getting exactly the correct results?   Please post sample data, and the results you would expect to get from it.

Comment: Sorry, Price(Rub) is a column, not a fuction.

Comment: And btw, you're going to want to think about how you want your trigger to behave when more than one row gets inserted at once.

Comment: In the table `OrderSupplier_Car` can be inserted multiple rows. No errors occur. Maybe that is the problem why i can't get the sum, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Invoice_Of_Supplier (OrderSupplierID, PaymentStatus, Cost)
VALUES (
( SELECT OrderSupplierID FROM inserted),
0,
(SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM Car
where Car.CarID = OrderOfSupplier_Car.CarID
and OrderOfSupplier_Car.OrderSupplierID in (select OrderSupplierID from inserted))
```

Comment: Please ***explain*** what you've changed - and why this is supposed to solve the problem.

Comment: doest work
p.s. I had to add JOIN OrderOfSupplier_Car in order to execute the query.

Comment: I replaced '=' to 'in' and I think that you can have a error in SUM([Price(RUB)]

Comment: What kind of error, it gets the sum when i remove `where` clause, but it is the sum of all cars and i dont need it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just select from inserted?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Invoice_Of_Supplier (OrderSupplierID, PaymentStatus, Cost)
SELECT
  i.OrderSupplierID,
  0,
  SUM(osc.[Price(RUB)])
FROM inserted i
inner join dbo.OrderOfSupplier_Car osc 
on osc.OrderSupplierID = i.OrderSupplierID
inner join dbo.Car c
ON c.CarID = osc.CarID 
group by i.OrderSupplierID
```

and I reckon you don't need that join to `Car` at all

Some questions to you: is this `after` or `instead of` trigger? On which table is it?

Comment: It is `AFTER` trigger. Sorry for misunderstaning. I have edited my qusetion.

Comment: This code doesn't create a row in `InvoiceOfSupplier` table at all. Mybe there is a way to change smth in my query, because the problem only with `Cost` field.

Comment: The problem is not with `Cost` field - the problem is with **no appropriate data** for this query.

Comment: what do you mean? Explain please. And how to solve it?

Comment: This data: `(SELECT SUM([Price(RUB)]) FROM Car
  JOIN OrderOfSupplier_Car AS osc ON osc.CarID=Car.CarID 
where osc.OrderSupplierID = (select OrderSupplierID from inserted)))` does not exist.

Comment: thank you, it seems to me I understood what was the problem. On the moment i inserted data in `Order_Of_Supplier`, there was no data in `Order_Of_Supplier_Car`.